# Get the list of PNG files in File Storage excluding _processed_ folder

Tags: typo3, extbase, fal

As topic says, I need to get only **unprocessed** PNG files.

My current approach is the following:

```
$fileExtensionFilter = $this->objectManager->get(FileExtensionFilter::class);
$fileExtensionFilter->setAllowedFileExtensions('png');

$storage->addFileAndFolderNameFilter([$fileExtensionFilter, 'filterFileList']);
$availablePngFiles = $storage->getFileIdentifiersInFolder($storage->getRootLevelFolder(false)->getIdentifier(), true, true);

foreach ($availablePngFiles as $pngFile) {
    if(!$storage->isWithinProcessingFolder($pngFile)) {
        $pngFileObject = $storage->getFile($pngFile);    
    }
}
```

So, it works, but I'd like to avoid the unnecessary `isWithinProcessingFolder()` lookup and get only the original unprocessed files, which will significantly reduce the number of loops.

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 core 7.6.19 does only ship with two filters: `FileExtensionFilter` and `FileNameFilter`, which actually is a "hidden file filter".

You could write your own file filter and filter in there, but that's way more work than keeping those two lines of code.